# Rotation Driven by Position - Driver Issue When Rendering

Tags: rigging, drivers

My latest rig in Blender 2.8 contains a ball that is supposed to roll on the floor. I already got it **working in the viewport**, but only until I hit the Render Button. **When rendering**, Blender completely ignores that driver, leaving the ball's rotation still.

Here is how the driver of the ball's axis-angle rotation W is set up:

[image: Ball driver]

CTL_TranslateScale is a parent of the driven ball and is therefore responsible for the ball's translation. *(Should I use a self reference instead? Could not make that one work, yet)*.

CTL_Master is the root of the control rig.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you really have to use a script? you can achieve same results with drivers

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. The Drivers - at least in this case and at least in 2.82 - update only if the current frame is changed manually by user. If it is changed by script (which Render Animation also is) Drivers ignore it. You can check it by typing in Blender Console `C.scene.frame_current = 5` - or any other frame number - and you'll see, that your object rotation stays unchanged though your frame has changed. More to say, for example if you are at the frame 5, manually change frame to 4 and than back to 5 - the result on the frame 5 will be different than if you would change frame to 6 and than back to 5.

Blender Drivers are buggy. I'd suggest to use Animation Nodes addon instead, it works more stable in general.