# Constrainted objects displaced during rendering animation

Tags: rendering, animation, constraints, drivers, memory-management

Faced the following problem. When I've rendered an animation, some details were not where they should be according to the timeframe. This problem occurs only when rendering an animation (3 problematic frames out of 100), if each “problematic" frame is rendered separately, each detail is in its right place. I guess this is not entirely correct from the point of optimization, but all the moving parts of the model are sets of constants and drivers, no rig (not yet, but I will return to this later). Please, tell me in which direction to look info about the missing and shifting parts? I have feelings that this is somehow related to the loading objects into the memory, because before i've upgraded from 16Gb to the 32Gb RAM i've could render only 3 consecutive frame, after that all progress have been freezing.

[image: Displasements during render]

[image: MissingDetail during render]

Here is my blend file if it helps
https://drive.google.com/open?id=16xDPaeUxWG3jUMsxfpa8RL2BmdRj3AU7

Comment: If you use Blender Drivers, [it can be a bug.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173386/81172)

Comment: Thanks. If it so, it seems that the only workaround is to re-render problematic frames one by one